# Angular 2 Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I have a question according to Angular 2 directives. I want to recreate my Angular 1 Application with Angular 2 but I got stuck at a directive. 
The one in Angular 1 looks like this:

```
app.directive('starRating', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template:   '<ul class="rating">' +
                    '<li ng-repeat="star in stars">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon" ng-class="star.class" aria-hidden="true">' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>',
    scope: {
        ratingValue: '=',
        max: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.stars = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
            if(i < scope.ratingValue){
                scope.stars.push({
                    class: "glyphicon-star"
                });
            } else {
                scope.stars.push({
                    class: "glyphicon-star gray"
                });
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

and I call it in my html file like this:

```
<div star-rating rating-value="movie.rating" max="5" ></div>
```

It's just a somple movielist with a name and the rating. Through the directive, I want to create just 5 stars and depending on the rating, the number of stars should be filled.

Is it possible to do such in Angular 2 aswell? If so, how would it be done? I cant find any proper code example or tutorial.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/blob/master/APM%20-%20Final/app/shared/star.component.ts, https://github.com/AngularClass/rating-stars/blob/master/src/stars.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found myself a fitting solution:

in the component i just added a function

```
getClass(index, rating) {
    if (index < rating) {
        return 'glyphicon-star';
    } else {
       return 'glyphicon-star-empty gray';
    }
}
```

in my HTML i call it like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
   <ul class="rating">
       <li *ngFor="let n of [0,1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
           <span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="getClass(i, rating)"></span>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```